# How can I include a child object mapping using AutoMapper when the source objects have no inheritance relationship?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an object model something like this:

```cs
public class Concert {
    public Band Band { get; set; }
    public ConcertVenue Venue { get; set; }
}

public class TicketOrder { 
    public Concert Concert { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

// DTOs for email and web views:
public class ConcertDto {
  public string Artist { get; set; }
  public string Venue { get; set; }
}

public class TicketOrderDto : ConcertDto {
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using AutoMapper to map domain objects to DTOs. The DTOs here have an inheritance relationship that doesn't exist in the domain model (because when I send an email about a ticket order, I want to include all the information about the concert)

I have a mapping defined like this:

```cs
config.CreateMap<Concert, ConcertDto>()
  .ForMember(dto => dto.Artist, opt => opt.MapFrom(concert => concert.Band.Name))
  .ForMember(dto => dto.Venue, opt => opt.MapFrom(concert => concert.GetVenueSummary());

config.CreateMap<TicketOrder, ConcertDto>()
  .ForMember(dto => dto.Artist, opt => opt.MapFrom(concert => concert.Band.Name))
  .ForMember(dto => dto.Venue, opt => opt.MapFrom(concert => concert.GetVenueSummary())
  .ForMember(dto => dto.CustomerName, optn.MapFrom(order => order.Customer.FullName))
;
```

There's some duplication in those maps, and what I *want* to do is to reuse the `Concert > ConcertViewData` mapping when I map the `TicketOrderDto`:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<TicketOrder, TicketOrderDto>()
  // This is what I *want* but isn't valid AutoMapper syntax:
  .IncludeMembers(dto => dto, order => order.Concert)
  .ForMember(dto => dto.CustomerName, optn.MapFrom(order => order.Customer.FullName));
```

but this fails with:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Only member accesses are allowed. 
   dto => dto (Parameter 'memberExpressions')
   at AutoMapper.ExpressionExtensions.EnsureMemberPath(LambdaExpression exp, String name)
```

Calling `.IncludeBase<>` doesn't work, because `ConcertOrder` doesn't derive from `Concert`.

Is there an easy way to import one map into another but specify that it should map from a child object of the source type? i.e. "hey, please map source.Child onto this, and then run the regular source > this mapping?"

Comment: Define an interface in your domain objects and `Include` that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to make an assumption here, but I believe the mapping should be from `TicketOrder` to `TicketOrderDto`, and not `ConcertDto` (which contains no `CustomerName` property) as the given models don't match the given mapping configuration.

In that case, you should be able to use `.AfterMap()` on ticket mapper configuration to map from `Concert` to `ConcertDto`.

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<TicketOrder, TicketOrderDto>()            
    .ForMember(d => d.CustomerName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Order.Customer.Name))
    .AfterMap((s, d, context) => context.Mapper.Map(s.Concert, d));
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct - error in my code (which I have corrected). And your solution works, too. Thank you.